# plotlyの結果をiframeを使ってphp(web上)で表示したい

Tags: python, php

pythonとplotlyを使い、plotlyで描いた結果（図）をphpで書いているwebsite上で表示したいと今努力しております。しかし、困ったことにうまく結果がphp上で表示されませんので、改良方法を教えていただけたら幸いです。

先にpythonとphpのプログラムを記します。
その下に困っている点を質問を説明させていただきます。

## 1. python用のプログラム (plotly.test.py)

```
import plotly
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Layout

plotly.offline.plot({
    "data": [Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[4, 3, 2, 1])],
    "layout": Layout(title="hello world")
})
```

## 2. php用のプログラム(実際にはhtmlしか使っておりません。)(plotly_test.display.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<div class="plotly_test">
    <iframe src="temp-plot.html" seamlesss="seamless"></iframe><br>
</div>

</html>
```

行っていることは、

```
python plotly.test.py
```

を動かし、temp-plot.htmlを作成しいています。
作成されたhtmlを上記のphpを使って、web上で表示するだけの簡単なプログラムです。

ここで問題なのは、php上で表示された図がつぶれてしまい、うまく表示されません。
plotlyを使っていますので、図自体はinteractiveに表現されていますので、図を拡大しましたが、線などすべて消えてしまっている状態です。
temp-plot.htmlだけを表示しますと、正しく表示されますので、phpのiframeで何か問題が発生しているのではないかと考えています。

最終的には、実際のtemp-plot.htmlで表示される図の縮小版（25%縮小図）をweb上で表示したいだけなのですが、そのようなことは可能でしょうか？

iframeでwidthやheightを使いますと、図全体のサイズを変えることはできます。しかし、図を正しく表示するためには、サイズを大きくする必要があります。
(わかりにくい説明で申し訳ないです。)
具体的な例では、iframe内のwidth=760やheight=1000の状態ですと、正しく図は表示されます。
しかし、図が大きい過ぎます。
これを（例えばwidth=180やheight=250）小さいサイズで、図を正しく表示したいです。

どうしても自分では解けなく、困っておりましたので、ここに質問させていただきました。

もし解決方法をお知りでしたら、ご教授をお願いします。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: temp-plot.htmlを貼り付けることは難しいですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。貼り付けるというのは、pngみたいなイメージに変換して、それを張り付けるということなのでしょうか？その場合、plotlyで作成された図が、interactiveに動かなくなってしまう可能性があります。いつもはhtmlをiframeで表示していますが、ご指摘された点から、別の方法もあるのかと思いました。貼り付け方法でもう少しご教授をしていただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: htmlソースをご提示いただくということです。iframeの中身が表示されないということなので、作成されたhtml自体に問題がある可能性があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの理解不足で、お手数をおかけして、大変申し訳ございませんでした。質問に回答する形で、いかに貼り付けます。

Comment: htmlファイル自体を見ますと、正しくは表示されるのです。
コードのシェアの仕方に問題があるかもしれませんが、以下のsiteにコピペしておきます。よろしくお願いします。
http://collaboncode.com/#/workspace/plotly_problem